# Какие в 2021 году существуют подходы для обеспечения параллельной разработки проекта и зависимости для него в NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, npm

Зачастую нам нужно, чтобы всякие вспомогательные утилиты, создаваемые в ходе проекта, можно было вынести в библиотеку и переиспользовать в другом проекте. Но как только библиотека опубликована в npm и она становится node_module-ем, её станет труднее отлаживать. Мы можем захотеть что-то исправить в библиотеке и посмотреть реакцию в основном проекте на внесённые исправления. Возможно, понадобятся новые правки, и тогда процесс выпуска большого количества новых версий с целью отладки станет кошмаром.

Определимся с задачей и с тем, что такое "хороший подход".

1. Мы можем разрабатываемую библиотеку подключить её как любую опубликованную npm-зависимость с указанием в package.json и она после установки появится в `node_modules`.
2. Мы можем откладывать публикацию зависимости на неопределённый срок, при этом этот никак не должно мешать её использованию в наших проектах.
3. Как только мы вносим исправления в зависимость - на проектах это тут же отражается.

Я знаю следующие подходы:

1. npm link

---

Символическая ссылка. В директории зависимости мы вводим `npm link`, а в проекте -`npm link <имя_зависимости>`. Тогда в `node_modules` появится что-то вроде ярлыка на папку с зависимостью (не уверен, что это простой ярлык в стандартном понимании).

Существенный недостаток метода в том, что как только мы поставим в проект ещё какую зависимость с помощью `npm install`, символическая ссылка пропадёт из `node_modules`. Придётся снова её устанавливать.  Кроме того, если проект разрабатывается в команде, то придётся каким-либо способом доносить до других сотрудников, какие локальные зависимости надо "линковать".

2. lerna

---

Насколько мне известно, lerna также работает с символическими ссылками, только при добавлении новых зависимостей берёт на себя рутину по повторному добавлению пропавших ссылок.

Недостаток инструмента:

1. В последнее время даже в терминале, запущенном от имени администратора, lerna часто прерывает операцию с ошибкой `operation not permitted`. Почитать GitHub - так там лишь рекомендации типа "стукнуть молотком по станку, и тогда раза с четвёрного он должен запуститься". Видимо, сами разработчики не понимают природу этой ошибки, а из за-неё добавление одной зависимости может затянуться минут на 10. Неприятно и то, что Lerna в процессе установки зависимостей редактирует package.json, в частности, удаляет поле `scripts`. При возникновении ошибки, `package.json` так и останется "неубранным".
2. Добавить набор нескольких определённых зависимостей в несколько определённых пакеты - сложно и рутинно.
3. Да и вообще, зачастую Lerna без посторонней помощи не может выполнить даже такие элементарные вещи как удаление зависимости.

Я и сам использую Lern-у года 2, но приведённые выше дефекты заставляют меня подумать об альтернативах.

3. Yarn Workspaces

---

Этот подход лично мне мало знаком, но если он хороший, то пожалуйста, опишите его в Вашем ответе.

4. Локальная зависимсоть

Современные версии Npm позволяют ссылаться за локальные зависимости:

```
{
  "name": "baz",
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
  }
}
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417065/4818123)

Могу предположить, что это лучше, чем обычная символическая ссылка, так как после установки новых зависимостей локальные зависимости остаются. Единственное, плохо что на другом компьютере возможно придётся заменить пути на актуальные, но на самом деле Lerna эту проблему не решает, так как она подразумевает, что проект и зависимости объеденены в общий репозиторий.

Answer (score 0):

Тут корень проблемы, что в мешаете в одну куча два совершенно разных сценария.

Первый - это локальная разработка. Тут нужно уметь подменять модуль в основном проекте на локальный, над которым идет разработка. Для этого годятся символический ссылки или локальные зависимости. Проблемы с ними, которые вы описали, не касаются этого сценария.

Второй сценарий это CI и использование еще неопубликованых публично версий модуля. Т.е. необходимость уметь создать новую версию модуля (протестированную локально) и опубликовать ее в какой-то вариант приватного репозитория (я не настолько знаком c npm, но поиск показывает что есть варианты от [scope-ов](https://docs.npmjs.com/package-scope-access-level-and-visibility) до установки [приватных](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575627/can-you-host-a-private-repository-for-your-organization-to-use-with-npm) репозиториев), который будет доступен как CI системе, так и для разворачивания на dev/QA/Staging окружениях.

В этом случае вы публикуете новую версию в такой приватный репозиторий и основном проекте ее указываете. Теперь можно тестировать новую версию основного проекта с новой версией зависимосит. После того как вы протестируете новую версию, вы ее просто публикуете в публичный репозиторий.